# Pandas Iterrows: Faster Alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I am trying to speed up one of my functions. I have read that 'vectorization' is the fastest way to run these types of operations in Pandas, but how is this (or anything else faster) achievable with this code:

##### Dummy data

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : [33, 75, 464, 88, 34], 'imp_flag' : [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'donor_index' : [3, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 0]})

>>> a
   var1  imp_flag  donor_index
0    33         1          3.0
1    75         0          NaN
2   464         0          NaN
3    88         1          4.0
4    34         1          0.0
```

##### The operation in question

```
for index, row in a[a['imp_flag'] == 1].iterrows():
    new_row = a[a.index == row.donor_index]
    b = b.append(new_row)
```

##### Expected output

```
>>> b
   var1  imp_flag  donor_index
1    75         0          NaN
1    75         0          NaN
2   464         0          NaN
```

Comment: The output you provide does not match the return of your code. Is this expected? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that I do not understand

How is it possible that your dataFrame returns Nan values in donor_index if there are no Nan value when you create *a*

```python
a = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : [33, 75, 464, 88, 34], 'imp_flag' : [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], 'donor_index' : [3, 1, 2, 4, 0]})

>>> a
   var1  imp_flag  donor_index
0    33         1            3
1    75         0            1
2   464         0            2
3    88         1            4
4    34         1            0
```

Are you sure that in your example the selection `a[a['imp_flag'] == 1]` is correct? It seems the way you get that results on *b* is the opposite `a[a['imp_flag'] == 0]`

Then, do you really need duplicated values in dataFrame **b**?

My solution is the following:

```python
idxs = a[a.imp_flag == 0].donor_index
b = a.iloc[idxs]
# or in one-line b = a.iloc[a[a.imp_flag == 0].donor_index]

>>> b
   var1  imp_flag  donor_index
1    75         0            1
2   464         0            2
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to subselect rows if imp_flag equals 1

You can simply use [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to match the relevant rows:

```
b = a.loc[a.query('imp_flag == 1')['donor_index']]
```

Alternatively, you can [index and select your data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) with:

```
b = a.loc[a[a['imp_flag'] == 1]['donor_index']]
```

output:

```
   var1  imp_flag  donor_index
3    88         1            4
4    34         1            0
0    33         1            3
```